# get records from previous year based on month and year and status

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the below table:

Created column which has dates
Status column which has values like open, closed, resolved

I would like to get only those records which are on open status and created value is of previous month. I would like to take care if the **year changes** too. Like Created Date is 2016-12-31 and Current Date is 2017-01-01

Below is my query:

```
select (case when Status_Flag = 'open' and (DATEPART(MONTH,Created) = DATEPART(Month,GetDate()) -1 OR 
(DATEPART(MONTH,Created) = DATEPART(Month,GetDate()) -1 OR DATEPART(YEAR,Created) < DATEPART(YEAR,GetDate()))) then 1 else 0 end) as Inc_BroughtForward from <table_name> where status = 'open'
```

Please let me know if my logic is correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from <table_name>
where status = 'open'
    and Created between DATEADD(month, -2, DATEADD(day, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE()))) and DATEADD(day, -1, DATEADD(month, -1, DATEADD(day, 1, (EOMONTH(GETDATE())))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Found one solution:

```
select

(case when Status = 'open' and DATEDIFF(MONTH, Created, GETDATE()) = 1  then 1 else 0 end) as Inc_BroughtForward 

from <table_name>
```